# How to use Jmeter to test all links on page means i want to check whether all links on page, works or not?

Tags: hyperlink, jmeter, web-crawler, broken-links, linkparser

I have some idea that, HTML link parser, HTTP sampler will help..I try to use it but unfortunatly didn't succeed in doing so..

Will act something like spider...

Comment: I think its functional testing and not performance, Though Jmeter is not designed to do such tasks but still if you want to do it then possibly no other way than recording script for all links (which is same as doing it manually)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Use HTML Link Parser as follows:

- Thread Group

  - Initial HTTP Request to `yourdomain.org`
  - [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) (can be blank)

    - HTTP Request which will check links. Use `yourdomain.org` as a Server Name and `.*` as Path

      - HTML Link Parser

This scenario will visit all the links. However it will stop on the first failure and you won't be able to tell whether only one link is broken or there are more.

**Option 2**

Use i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) in combination with [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller). This scenario will iterate each single link so you will be able to tell which one is broken.

For more information on implementing Option 2 refer to [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) guide.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Link Parser - we can create a robust test plan just by using Regular Expression Extractor.

Find the sample tets plan.

[image]

For more info, visit the below link.

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-find-broken-links/

Answer (score 0):

Use LinkChecker.It is a tool for test all links present on webpage.